# Styles not getting properly applied to the <ul> tag

Tags: html, css

I am have implemented an input control and button in my table in the `Angular 7` application. When the user enters text in the input control and clicks the add button, the text is entered in the `<ul>` list. At the moment the `<ul>` list is all distorted and I believe it is because of its container. The example that I am referring to is using `<div>`. Could somebody help me out and let me know what the issue is

Following is the link that I am referring to and trying to make it look like the one in the example

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kelqedbdqlb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.css

This is how it looks on my screen

[image]

HTML

```
<table style="width:100%" *ngIf="ManagerStrategyDetails">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="width:100%">
                            <tr *ngIf="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Firm Name<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FirmName}}</span>
                                    <ng-select *ngIf="EditMode" [items]="Firms" [virtualScroll]="true"
                                        [loading]="loading" bindLabel="Name" style="width:450px;height:27px;" bindValue="Id"
                                        appendTo="body" (scroll)="onFirmsScroll($event)" placeholder="Select Firm"
                                        (change)="onExistingStrategyChange($event)"
                                        (scrollToEnd)="onFirmsScrollToEnd()">
                                    </ng-select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr *ngIf="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Manager Name<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.ManagerName}}</span>
                                    <div  *ngIf="EditMode"> 

                                        <input class="etg-text-box" style="width: 450px; float: left;" #heroName />

                                        <button  (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">
                                            Add
                                        </button>

                                    </div>

                                    <ul class="heroes">
                                            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
                                              <a >
                                                <span class="badge"></span> {{hero.name}}
                                              </a>
                                              <button class="delete" title="delete hero"
                                                (click)="delete(hero)">x</button>
                                            </li>
                                          </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Fund Strategy Name<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px"
                                        *ngIf="NewStrategyMode || EditMode">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName}}</span>
                                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" class="etg-text-box" style="width: 450px" type="text"
                                        name="fsname" [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Investment Status<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px"
                                        *ngIf="NewStrategyMode || EditMode">*</span></td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.InvestmentStatus != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.InvestmentStatus.Name:
                                ''}}</td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [disabled]="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy"
                                        [(ngModel)]="DefaultInvestmentStatus"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.InvestmentStatuses" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngIf="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Underlying Fund Name<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName}}</span>
                                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" class="etg-text-box" style="width: 450px" type="text"
                                        name="fsname" [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Strategy Type<span style="color:red; padding-left:5px"
                                        *ngIf="NewStrategyMode || EditMode">*</span></td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyType != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyType.Name:
                                ''}}</td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyType"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyTypes" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Strategy<span style="color:red; padding-left:5px"
                                        *ngIf="NewStrategyMode || EditMode">*</span></td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.Strategy != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.Strategy.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Strategy"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Strategies" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngIf="UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Reporting Strategy<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px"
                                        *ngIf="NewStrategyMode || EditMode">*</span></td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.ReportingStrategy != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.ReportingStrategy.Name:
                                ''}}</td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.ReportingStrategy"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.ReportingStrategies" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngIf="!ManagerStrategyDetails.IsNew">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Primary Fund</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryFund != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryFund.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryFund"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Funds" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngIf="ManagerStrategyDetails.IsCoinvestment && !ManagerStrategyDetails.IsNew">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Representative Product</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.RepresentativeProduct != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.RepresentativeProduct.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.RepresentativeProduct"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.RepresentativeProducts" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Primary Analyst</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryAnalyst != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryAnalyst.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PrimaryAnalyst"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Analysts" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableItem header">Secondary Analyst</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.SecondaryAnalyst != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.SecondaryAnalyst.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.SecondaryAnalyst"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Analysts" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Benchmark 1</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark1 != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark1.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark1"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmarks" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Benchmark 2 (HF)</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark2 != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark2.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark2"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.HFBenchmarks" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Benchmark 3</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark3 != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark3.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmark3"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.Benchmarks" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Peer Group 1</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup1 != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup1.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup1"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroups1" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Peer Group 2</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup2 != null ? ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup2.Name: ''}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <kendo-combobox style="width:450px"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroup2"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings"
                                        [data]="ManagerStrategyDetails.PeerGroups2" [filterable]="true"
                                        [kendoDropDownFilter]="filterSettings" textField="Name" valueField="Id">
                                    </kendo-combobox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr *ngIf="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Contact Person<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName}}</span>
                                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" class="etg-text-box" style="width: 450px" type="text"
                                        name="fsname" [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngIf="!UserProfile.CanCreateProspectiveManagerStrategy">
                                <td class="tableItem header">Address<span
                                        style="color:red; padding-left:5px">*</span></td>
                                <td class="tableItem">
                                    <span *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName}}</span>
                                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" class="etg-text-box" style="width: 450px" type="text"
                                        name="fsname" [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyName">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <!-- <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Make Anonymous</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.IsAnonymus ? "Yes" : "No"}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbIsAnonymus" class="epg-checkbox"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.IsAnonymus">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tableLastItem header">Restrict From Liquid Alts Team</td>
                                <td *ngIf="!EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    {{ManagerStrategyDetails.IsRestrictFromLiquidAltsTeam ? "Yes" : "No"}}
                                </td>
                                <td *ngIf="EditMode" class="tableLastItem">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbIsRestrictFromLiquidAltsTeam" class="epg-checkbox"
                                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.IsRestrictFromLiquidAltsTeam">
                                </td>
                            </tr> -->




                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 60%;">
                        <div class="desc-header">Fund Strategy Description
                            <span class="pull-right"
                                style="font-style: italic; font-size: 12px">{{ManagerStrategyDetails.DescLastReviewer}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div style="font-size: 12px; border: solid 1px lightgrey; height: 448px;overflow: scroll;">
                            <ckeditor [id]="'ckeditor_strategy_desc'" style="font-size: 11px;" *ngIf="EditMode"
                                debounce="500" [config]="EditorConfig"
                                [(ngModel)]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyDescription"> </ckeditor>
                            <div style="padding: 25px" *ngIf="!EditMode"
                                [innerHTML]="ManagerStrategyDetails.FundStrategyDescription"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

css

```
/* HeroesComponent's private CSS styles */
.heroes {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
}
.heroes li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.heroes li:hover {
  color: #607D8B;
  background-color: #DDD;
  left: .1em;
}

.heroes a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}

.heroes a:hover {
  color:#607D8B;
}

.heroes .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
  background-color:#405061;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  top: -4px;
  height: 1.8em;
  min-width: 16px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: .8em;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

button {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-family: Arial;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #cfd8dc;
}

button.delete {
  position: relative;
  left: 194px;
  top: -32px;
  background-color: gray !important;
  color: white;
}
```

Update 1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Verticle Middle

```
/** for close verticle middle replace your Css With this **/

button.delete {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ee6e0b !important;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}



/** for verticle middle text replace your css with this **/

.heroes li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  margin: .5em;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.heroes a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 36px;
}

.heroes .badge{
  display: block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FAE7D6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto 4px auto auto;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the updates versoin of your CSS

/* HeroesComponent's private CSS styles */

```
.heroes {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
}
.heroes li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .5em;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.heroes li:hover {
  color: #607D8B;
  background-color: #DDD;
  left: .1em;
}

.heroes a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.heroes a:hover {
  color:#607D8B;
}

.heroes .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  background-color: #405061;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: auto 4px auto auto;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
}

button {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-family: Arial;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #cfd8dc;
}


button.delete {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray !important;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 82%;
}
```

/*
Copyright Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/

Comment: I need to render the text in the middle of the box. Its now rendering at the bottom of the box

Comment: I have reduced the height if li and badge to  height: 30px; I probably would need to adjust the text in the li. could you tell me which property affects it

Comment: I have updated the post with the screenshot. If you notice even the x is not in the centre

Comment: Please provide me link

Comment: If you reduce the height of li and badge also reduce line-height from badge

Comment: please update your example link so that i can check your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197385/discussion-between-sunil-rajput-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Do these following changes

In HTML make changes to  tag inside the list as below:

```
<a >
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <span class="badge"></span>
    <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

In CSS make changes to .heroes a tag as below:

```
.heroes a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

For reference check this codepen link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqvOqx?editors=1100